# Log AWS API Gateway Deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I need a way to log API gateway deployments (date/time, user, swagger diff etc.). Is there an event thats fired that i can attach a lambda to, or alternatively is this information already available on the dashboard somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps: have you looked at CloudTrail?

Answer (score 0):

As Krishna mentioned, [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail.html) can capture API events (both from the AWS console as well as the AWS APIs) for API Gateway, including the deployment of APIs. Since [CloudTrail stores the events in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail.html), you can take advantage of S3 bucket notifications as a means to trigger your Lambda function.